# Combining 2 IF statements in one

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have these 2 IF statements in 2 seperate cells and would like to make them function in one cell. I have tried a few ways of combining but cannot make it work. Can an IF statement expert help me combine these 2?

1 st.

```
=IF(K21<0.01,("DTI Ratio Available "&TEXT(K21*-1,"$ 0.00")),("DTI Ratio Short by  "&TEXT(K21,"$ 0.00")))
```

2nd.

```
=IF(K20<0.01,"Housing Ratio Available "&TEXT(K20*-1,"$ 0.00"),"Housing Ratio Short by "&TEXT(K20,"$ 0.00"))
```

Thank you very very much

Comment: so you want both text strings in the cell?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=CONCATENATE(
    IF(K21<0.01,("DTI Ratio Available "&TEXT(K21*-1,"$ 0.00")),("DTI Ratio Short by "&TEXT(K21,"$ 0.00"))),
    " ",
    IF(K20<0.01,"Housing Ratio Available "&TEXT(K20*-1,"$ 0.00"),"Housing Ratio Short by "&TEXT(K20,"$ 0.00"))
            )
```

Comment: Correct, you could also do `=A1 & " " & A2`